# Is it possible to change junit_suite_name depending on pytest parameters?

Tags: python, junit, pytest, test-suite

I'm trying to create a test report in JUnit XML format while running `pytest` on Jenkins.

The default test suite name is "pytest", but I want to change the name depending on parameter values.

For example,

in `conftest.py`, I have

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--site", type=str.upper, action="append", default=[],
                     help="testing site")
```

And I want to change `junit_suite_name` option depending on the site value.

I read pytest document but I found that you can change the name in config file like this

```
[pytest]
junit_suite_name = my_suite
```

or on command line, `-o junit_suite_name.`

But this way, the name will always the same for all test cases.
Is there a way to group the suite name conditionally?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to set `junit_suite_name` programmatically, depending on `--site` argument?

Answer (score 3):

You can change ini options programmatically via setting or changing values in `config.inicfg` dict. For example, do it in the custom [`pytest_configure`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_configure) hookimpl:

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    if config.option.site == 'foo':
        config.inicfg['junit_suite_name'] = 'bar'
```

The suite name in the JUnit report will now be `bar` when you run `pytest --site=foo`.